# How to log out of your android studio account using Firebase Auth?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

There is an application with Firebase Auth, the sign out function lies in the MainActivity, but the output must be implemented from the MenuActivity, Intent does not work because the input is executed and the user value is initialized. Need to call the function sign Out of other activities, I don't know how to do it, please explain or tell where to read about it.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.ecohelp;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;


    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    View.OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "EmailPassword";

private EditText mEmailField;
private EditText mPasswordField;
public ProgressDialog pd;

protected FirebaseAuth mAuth;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);








    mEmailField = findViewById(R.id.fieldEmail);
    mPasswordField = findViewById(R.id.fieldPassword);


    findViewById(R.id.emailSignInButton).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.emailCreateAccountButton).setOnClickListener(this);



    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    updateUI(currentUser);
}

private void createAccount(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Создание аккаунта" + email);
    if (validateForm()) {
        return;
    }
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

    pd.show();
    pd.setMessage("Регистрация");


    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            pd.hide();
            Log.d(TAG, "Аккаунт успешно создан");
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            updateUI(user);
        } else {
            pd.hide();
            Log.w(TAG, "Ошибка создания аккаунта", task.getException());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ошибка создания аккаунта",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            updateUI(null);
        }

    });
}

private void signIn(String email, String password) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Вход" + email);
    if (validateForm()) {
        return;
    }
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.show();
    pd.setMessage("Вход");

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    pd.hide();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Вход через почту успешен");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    pd.hide();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Вход не вошелся", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ошибка входа",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }


            });
}


private boolean validateForm() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailField.setError("Пусто");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mEmailField.setError(null);
    }

    String password = mPasswordField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        mPasswordField.setError("Пусто");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        mPasswordField.setError(null);
    }

    return !valid;
}

protected void signOut() {
    mAuth.signOut();
    updateUI(null);
}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pd.hide();
    if (user != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.emailCreateAccountButton) {
        createAccount(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
    } else if (i == R.id.emailSignInButton) {
        signIn(mEmailField.getText().toString(), mPasswordField.getText().toString());
    }

}
```

MenuActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;



public class Menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.map) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (i == R.id.signOut) {





        }

    }
}
```

MenuActivity.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="164dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/maps"
    android:text="@string/map"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.451" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signOut"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="@string/signOut"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="422dp"
        android:layout_height="359dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/aaaaaaaaaaa" />
    </TableRow>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="434dp"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fieldEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="87dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fieldPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="84dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/emailCreateAccountButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/createAccount" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/emailSignInButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/signIn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()` in your second activity?

Comment: It helped me thanks if you can send me what it's called to have me pin this

Comment: You're welcome. What do you want me to send?

Comment: What should I Google to read about it

Comment: Did that line of code solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to know more about it.

Comment: Would you like me to post an answer for that?

Comment: Okay with my Google translator we do not understand each other, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can logout From current activity and then Use Intent to navigate into another activity.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int i = v.getId();
    if (i == R.id.map) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (i == R.id.signOut) {
         
         FirebaseAuth.getInstance.signOut();
         Intent navigateIntent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
         startActivity(navigateIntent);
           //so that when you click the back button, you won't have to able to go back the previous activity
         finish();
    }

}
}
```